# How to remove wine7.0-rc1 compiled from source?

Tags: command-line, wine, gnome-terminal, uninstall

I tried to uninstall wine7.0-rc1 but wine is still here.

This is what I type on my terminal:

**`wine --version`**

Here is the output, so the wine version

**`wine-7.0-rc1`**
So how to uninstall this wine version ?
Because I removed package of wine but wine is still here

---

My OS is ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I download wine7.0-rc1 from this website :

https://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/7.0/

Then I unpackaged the file tar.xz then I installed wine with these commands :

```
tar xf wine-7.0-rc1.tar.xz


./configure

make

sudo make install
```

I use the commands to uninstall wine

> sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-stable wine-stable-amd64 sudo
> apt clean && sudo apt autoclean sudo apt remove && sudo apt autoremove

---

I tried this command

```
 sudo make uninstall
```

and then I got this :

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
```

Comment: You cannot use `apt` to remove wine, because you did not use `apt` to install it.

Comment: Yes it answered to the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To uninstall this version of wine, you need to go to the source directory (which you obtained by extracting the .tar.xz file), and then run `sudo make uninstall`.